# jquery don't work after load page with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm building a website and i had a plugin working fine.

But when i tried to insert it into my website it stop working. After some test i noticed it's happening after a load the content with ajax. Searching here, i saw a similar question and the solution was to use the .on() event with Jquery. I did that, but stilldoesn't work.

What am i doing wrong? (i'm new to jquery, don't understand that much)

Here is what i have:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="split">Split</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"><!-- content ajax -->

</div><!-- /content ajax -->


    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/cbpSplitLayout.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js (load the page)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#content').load('content/home.php');

   $('#list').on( 'click', 'a', function() {
       console.log('log confirm');
       var page = $(this).attr('href');

       $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
       return false;
});
});
```

And the plugin i'm trying to run is a external plugin: Split Layout.
I got it from this website here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/25/split-layout/

And this is a pastebin to it's js script: http://pastebin.com/yfJXGR8f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is JQuery library included in the pages called by AJAX ? That could be the solution simply include

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

on your AJAX pages' `<head>` tag

Comment: This is not the case because the plugin to run the split screen doesn't use jquery. Only need to use modernizr, classie and it's own script (cbpSplitLayout.js). The jquery.js i have is to run the loading of the pages into the div #container. I'm the whole day trying to find a solution for this, but i can't. Edit: By the way, i tried to do this after you said, and can confirm it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, i did tried what you said, but with a different script. I placed the cbpSplitLayout.js in the respective laoding page and it's now workin. Thanks for the tip =D